# LinkDb: adding segment & SolrIndexer takes lots of time

Tags: nutch

Below is the command that I am running to index pages.

```
bin/nutch crawl bin/urls -solr http://localhost:8983/solr/ -dir crawl -depth 2 -topN 15
```

The fetching happens pretty quickly but LinkDb:adding segments and SolrIndexer steps are taking lot of time, as I run above command repeatedly the time increases. My requirement is such that I want to index pages as fast as possible because links disappear pretty quickly (within 2 mins). I want to decrease this time to a very small figure, what should I do to make this possible?

If I only wanted to index URL and title of the page, will doing so do any good to indexing speed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have a static seedlist then you can delete "crawl" folder each time you want to run the nutch! it would save a lot's of time for you!
every time you run nutch your segments growth so linkdb gonna take more time!
Also you can create a thread and pass this part of job to it, but you have to handle segmenting buy yourself!

Comment: this seems helpful I will you know if it helps. Meanwhile can you please provide any reference link for what you have said